# HttpClient is taking longer time to return an array response

Tags: php, httpclient, symfony4

I am calling an external API using `HttpClient` This request is taking about 30 seconds to response an array. Is there some way I can reduce this response time ?

```
    $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $url, [
        'x-auth-token' => $this->session->get('token'),
        'x-auth-key'   => $token
    ]);

    return $response->toArray();
```

Comment: The callee's fault?

Comment: It depends. Have you concluded that it's the above code that causes the response time and not the server you're calling that just is slow? Have you checked the network connection between the two servers? The server load? It could be numerous reasons for a slow response time. What debugging have you done to narrow the issue down to this specific code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Code above is what I have tried so far, to check if its my side fault.

Comment: How are you going to optimize your code if you don't know what you need to optimize it for though? You should do some digging and find out exactly where/what the issue is before you start to randomly change arbitrary pieces of code. If your car doesn't run properly, you find out why, you don't just start swapping out parts one by one without knowing if they are relevant or not.